# Bi-Directional Logic Level converter 1.8V-5V using MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, converter, logic-level

I need to connect an Event Detection pin (pin of the NXP NTAG 5 component) to a GPIO of the NXP i.XM6 processor.

The problem is that the NTAG 5 pin has a logic level of 5V and the GPIO has a logic level of 1.8V.

So my idea was to make a simple 1.8V-5V logic level bidirectional converter using a MOSFET.

How do you think I can do this?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

[NTAG 5 boost datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTA5332.pdf)

Comment: You didn't provide the datasheet, but I doubt the event detection pin is bidirectionnal. Why do you need the level converter to be bidirectionnal?

Comment: You are right! The level converter does not need to be directional.